# Webkit iPhone App : How to dynamically change the user zoom (or scale, pich & zoom) in the viewport?

Tags: iphone, safari, webkit, scale, viewport

I use JQTouch for an iPhone app. JQtouch disable by default the possibility to pinch&zoom the page.
For one page (containing a big image), i need to enable the pinch & zoom feature.
This is easy :

```
var viewport = $("head meta[name=viewport]");
viewport.attr('content', 'width=320, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=10.0, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=1');
```

But after user has play with the pinch & zoom, I need to dynamically reset the zoom (scale) to the default. I tried to reset the viewport:

```
viewport.attr('content', 'width=320, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;');
```

After calling the above code, it's not possible to zoom anymore (because of user-scalable=0;), but it doesn't change the current scale to the default.

I am looking for something like setScale(1), or to change an attribute like current-scale=1

Any idea ?

Comment: I have found a smart solution here :

http://homepage.mac.com/jorgechamorro/cljs/076/

Need to test it deeper...

Comment: Unfortunately, once the user has manually pinch&zoom, the link above doesn't work anymore...

Maybe there is another solution for what I want to do. basically, I want to display an image, and let the user zoom in/out and to scroll while zooming. I tried something with iScroll, but I din't managed to get both horizontal and vertical scroll while zooming...
Anybody has an idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to reset the user scaling is to reload the page :

```
window.location.reload();
```

If you don't want to do that, you will need to add a script to zoom dynamically elements such as images with touch events. Here is an example of pinch&zoom with scrolling :

http://tlrobinson.net/projects/iphone-light-table/

It's easy to integrate this code in your project. just open the HTML source, copy the Javascript, and change the init() function regarding your needs.

Comment: Reloading does not work for resetting the zoom in my case. Do I need to add something e.g. to the script to make it reset due to reloading?

Comment: No, this code window.location.reload(); should reload the web page with the default scale (like the first loading)

Comment: note: reloading doesn't reset mobile safari's window scaling. :(

Comment: In my case I have no viewport tag, and I don't want to add one because I want all of the behaviors you get when you don't have one (browsers treat the site as a "legacy" site).. so there is no "initial zoom", and I assume that is why reloading this was doesn't reset the zoom for me -- but I want it to.